# setTag and getTag issue android listview

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

The first time listview is initiated, headers appear as expected. The same listview when i scroll down and come up, headers disappear. This problem is solved when i remove the set and getTag codes. But that hinders the performance of the listview. What am i doing wrong here that brings up the problem.

```
package com.mediaplayer.adapter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ReadLisstAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnScrollListener {
    private Activity activity;
    ArrayList<SongInfo> song_array;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    BaseAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
    Thread t;
    ImageDownloader imageLoader;
    SongInfoDatabase database;
    String searchString = "";
    DecimalFormat format;
    int min, sec, total;

    public ReadLisstAdapter(Activity activity2, ArrayList<SongInfo> song_array,
            ListView lv) {
        activity = activity2;
        this.song_array = song_array;
        this.lv = lv;
        imageLoader = new ImageDownloader(this,
                activity.getApplicationContext());

        database = new SongInfoDatabase(activity.getApplicationContext());
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.lv = lv;
        imageLoader.loadImage(0, 10);
        lv.setOnScrollListener(this);
        format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    }

    public ArrayList<SongInfo> getUrlList() {
        return song_array;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return song_array.size();
    }

    public ListView getListView() {
        return lv;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView duration;
        public TextView album;
        public TextView artist;
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView header;
        int pos;
    }

    public View getView(final int arg0, View vi, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (vi == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songlist_item, null);
            holder.header = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.label_header_textview);
            holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.song_textView);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songlist_imageView);
            holder.album = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.song_album_textView);
            holder.artist = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.song_artist_textView);
            holder.duration = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.song_duration_textView);
            holder.pos = arg0;
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        try {


            holder.title.setText(song_array.get(arg0).getTitle());
            total = Integer.parseInt(song_array.get(arg0).getDuration()) / 1000;
            min = total / 60;
            sec = total % 60;
            holder.duration.setText(min + ":" + sec);
            holder.album.setText("from " + song_array.get(arg0).getAlbum());
            holder.artist.setText("by " + song_array.get(arg0).getArtist());

            Uri albumArtUri = Uri
                    .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            final Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri,
                    Long.parseLong(song_array.get(arg0).getAlbum_id()));
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(imageLoader.getDrawble(uri.toString()));
            if (song_array.get(arg0).getTitle().trim().toUpperCase(Locale.US)
                    .charAt(0) != song_array.get(arg0 - 1).getTitle().trim()
                    .toUpperCase(Locale.US).charAt(0)) {
                setSection(holder.header, song_array.get(arg0).getTitle());
            } else {
                holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            setSection(holder.header, song_array.get(arg0).getTitle());
        }

        return vi;
    }

    private void setSection(TextView text, String label) {
        text.setBackgroundColor(0xffe47168);
        text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        text.setText((label.substring(0, `enter code here`1) + "").toUpperCase());
        text.setTextSize(15);
        text.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (scrollState) {
        case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
            imageLoader.loadImage(lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(),
                    lv.getLastVisiblePosition());
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: here is the good sectioned adapter sample https://github.com/ItsRajesh4uguys/SimpleSectionAdapterAndroid

Comment: Not a solution, but just to let you know, you don't need to add all imports while providing code snippets. If you do that, your code becomes too lengthy and potential solution providers do not feel very inclined to go through the whole page by scrolling contents :)

Comment: Will follow it @the-dark-knight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE)` but nowhere there is a matching `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to make the header visible again when the a view is recycled to become a header.

Generally, your `getView()` should reconfigure everything in a recycled view. If there's an `if` branch for some customization, there should be an `else` branch that restores the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple.All you have to do is setVisibility to back View.VISIBLE in the if block.

```
 if (song_array.get(arg0).getTitle().trim().toUpperCase(Locale.US)
                .charAt(0) != song_array.get(arg0 - 1).getTitle().trim()
                .toUpperCase(Locale.US).charAt(0)) {
            setSection(holder.header, song_array.get(arg0).getTitle());
            holder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```